# JBoss EAP and OSX and "JBAS014612: Operation ("clean-obsolete-content") failed"

Tags: osx-yosemite, jboss6.x

Running IntelliJ 14.5.0, OSX 10.10.5, and JBoss EAP 6.4.0.

Looking for anyone that has any idea what's happening (I stumped the google with the error messages - zero results for "JBAS015976: Error cleaning obsolete content",  "JBAS014749: Operation handler failed").

Once in a while locally the following error is thrown, which doesn't appear to affect the application running:

```
10:01:59,148 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) JBAS014612: Operation ("clean-obsolete-content") failed - address: ([]): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.as.repository.HashUtil.hexStringToByteArray(HashUtil.java:62)
    at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentReference.getHash(ContentReference.java:66)
    at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepository$Factory$ContentRepositoryImpl.removeContent(ContentRepository.java:368)
    at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepository$Factory$ContentRepositoryImpl.markAsObsolete(ContentRepository.java:424)
    at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepository$Factory$ContentRepositoryImpl.cleanObsoleteContent(ContentRepository.java:400)
    at org.jboss.as.server.operations.CleanObsoleteContentHandler.execute(CleanObsoleteContentHandler.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:702) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:537) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:338) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:314) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1144) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:331) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:188) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$3.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:563) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$3.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:553) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.ContentRepositoryCleaner.cleanObsoleteContent(ContentRepositoryCleaner.java:132)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.ContentRepositoryCleaner$ContentRepositoryCleanerTask.run(ContentRepositoryCleaner.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]

10:01:59,151 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) JBAS015976: Error cleaning obsolete content JBAS014749: Operation handler failed: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug on Jboss.

[wildfly core issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-1304)

[Jboss EAP 6 issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1299189)